# With SameSite to Strict, how to block browsers not supporting the feature?

Tags: cookies, csrf, setcookie, samesite

Setting the "SameSite" attribute of the Set-Cookie HTTP response header to "Lax" or "Strict"  protects my application against CSRF attacks (only POST requests for "Lax").

But if I'm correct, this is the case only if the user uses a browser that actually supports this feature.

Then, what is the best way to block the usage of other browsers not supporting this feature?

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of would be to set a cookie with `SameSite=Strict` and then trigger a cross-site request where you can examine the cookies. If the cookie appears, the `SameSite` attribute has not been enforced.

This is kind-of what I do on https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me

1. You can see a cookie set with `Set-Cookie: ck05=vl05; SameSite=Strict`
2. The page creates a cross=site iframe:

```html
<iframe src="https://googlechromelabs.github.io/samesite-examples/crosssite-embed.html"></iframe>
```

3. The iframe makes a request back to `https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me/cookies.json`
4. The server checks the included cookies on that request - the `SameSite=Strict` cookie should not be included.